# Lithium power supply not working

Tags: power, alternative-power

Re: [Kuman Lithium Battery Pack Power Expansion Board with Switch + Micro USB Cable for Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, Pi 2 Model B & Pi 1 Model B+ A+ A KY68](http://kumantech.com/kuman-lithium-battery-pack-power-expansion-board-with-switch-micro-usb-cable-for-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-pi-2-model-b-amp-pi-1-model-b-a-a-ky68_p0287.html)

I just bought this for use with Pi3 model B and camera.  Charged it on the Pi until the red light went out. Then turned off Pi, unplugged power supply and then plugged in the battery power pack. Nothing happens. No light, no output, nothing. Took out the camera and still nothing.  Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your picture, it looks like the power switch is flipped off. If you look at the board oriented with *RPi PowerPack V1.2* at the top, you'll notice there's a switch at the very bottom of the board. Switch it to *On*.

I'm not sure if this matters, but in the images provided by your link, they all show the RPi being plugged into the top USB port. If they're ordered, it may make a difference.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought about a switch. No documents shipped with product and no info on website.  I'm up and running.